# How to merge two different List

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string> list1`, example values:

```
var list1 = new List<string>()
{
    "123", "1234", "12345",
};
```

I have a class:

```
public class TestClass {
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public int count{ get; set; }
}
```

and I have a `List<TestClass> list2`, example values:

```
var list2 = new List<TestClass>()
{
    new TestClass() { name = "12", count = 0 },
    new TestClass() { name = "123", count = 5 },
    new TestClass() { name = "1234", count = 20 },
};
```

I want to merge `list1` and `list2` and the result should be:

```
name        count
12          0
123         5
1234        20
12345       0
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Union`?

Comment: Union wont work with custom objects. Have to create Custom Comparator.

Comment: what are you trying to do, from your problem it looks like more than list the data structure should be a dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
var list1 = new List<string>()
{
    "123", "1234", "12345",
};

var list2 = new List<TestClass>()
{
    new TestClass() { name = "12", count = 0 },
    new TestClass() { name = "123", count = 5 },
    new TestClass() { name = "1234", count = 20 },
};

var merged =
    list2
        .Concat(list1.Select(x => new TestClass() { name = x, count = 0 }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.name)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
        .ToList();
```

It gives me:

[image: merged]

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<TestClass> lst1 = new List<TestClass>();
        lst1.Add(new TestClass(){name="One", count = 1});
        lst1.Add(new TestClass(){name="Two", count = 2});
        lst1.Add(new TestClass(){name="Three", count = 3});

        List<TestClass> lst2 = new List<TestClass>();
        lst2.Add(new TestClass(){name="Four", count = 4});
        lst2.Add(new TestClass(){name="Two", count = 2});
        lst2.Add(new TestClass(){name="Three", count = 3});

        var unionlst = lst1.Union(lst2, new TestClassComparer ());

        foreach(var x in unionlst){
            Console.WriteLine(x.name + ","+x.count);
        }
    }

    class TestClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestClass>
    { 
        public bool Equals(TestClass p1, TestClass p2)
        {
            return p1.name == p2.name && p1.count == p2.count;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(TestClass p)
        {
            return p.count;
        }
    }

    public class TestClass {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public int count{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

One,1

Two,2

Three,3

Four,4

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't compile.

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for. He gave sample input and the desired output. You've chosen to do something different (though similar).